# How do I display PayPal's IPN variables to a blogger.com webpage?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, blogger, paypal-ipn

I've written the following PayPal IPN Listener as a stand alone webapp in Google Apps Script; executed as me everyone has access. See Fig 1 and Embedded it with within one of the pages on my blogger site - https://???.blogspot.com/p/MyPage.html. (After checkout in PayPal is completed the customer is automatically redirected to this page) See Fig 2 for embed code.

The problem is that whenever I run the script I keep getting the following error:

> Script function not found: doGet

Fig 1.

```
function doPost(e) { 
  var isProduction = false;
  
  var strSimulator  = "https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
  var strLive = "https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
  var paypalURL = strSimulator;
  
  if (isProduction)  paypalURL = strLive;

  var payload = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + e.postData.contents;

  var options =
    {
      "method" : "post",
      "payload" : payload,
    };
    
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(paypalURL, options); //Handshake with PayPal - send acknowledgement and get VERIFIED or INVALID response
  
  if (resp == 'VERIFIED') {
    if (e.parameter.payment_status  == 'Completed') {
      if (e.parameter.receiver_email == 'my-email@example.com') {
        //Implement paid amount validation. If accepting payments in multiple currencies, use e.parameter.exchange_rate to convert to reference currency (USD) if paid in any other currency
        if (amountValid) {
        
          //All validated - can process the payment here
            var params = JSON.stringify(e);
            return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(' ').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);

          if (!(processSuccess)) {
            //Process of payment failed - raise notification to check it out

          }
        } else {
          //Payment does not equal expected purchase value
        }
      } else {
       //Request did not originate from my PayPal account 
      }
    } else {
     //Payment status not Completed 
    }
  } else
  {
   //PayPal response INVALID 
  }
}
```

Fig 2.

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" height="500" marginheight="0"  marginwidth="0" src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/My_Script_Id/exec?embedded=true" width="Auto">Loading...</iframe>
```

I tried calling the `doPost(e)` function from a `doGet(e)` function I created within the file; see Fig 3, but I only get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contents') (line 15, file "Code")

Fig 3.

```
function doGet(e) { 
doPost(e);
}
```

What should happen is, I would like to print out the PayPal IPN variables sent.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `I keep getting the following error: Script function not found: doGet` and "Fig 2." and your "Fig 3.". Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: `postData` is not included in the event object (`e`) of `doGet` such that `e.postData` is `undefined`. (Because it is a GET request). Besides, no data is sent by the iframe element. Please clarify your problem.

Comment: Unclear why anyone would want or need to integrate IPN in 2023. This product is extremely old and should be deprecated soon. Choose a better solution for what you're trying to accomplish. More broadly: (a) good checkout flow should not depend on the user being redirected after payment completion, though I'm not sure of a blogger App's suitability for a sensible integration, and (b) IPN does not involve redirecting the user's browser, if you are expecting the user's browser to have data when redirecting that would be PDT -- but this is even older and worse than IPN, stay away from it completely

Comment: Idfurw: I agree that the doGet event object would not return posted data. What did you mean when you said no data is sent by the Iframe element? To clarify, I am using blogger and apps script because it's free. I've created some PayPal add to cart buttons and placed them on my site. After the payment is made I would like to transfer the payment data from PayPal to a webpage where I can further process the information. Preston PHX: IPN may not be suitable due to the possible delays in transmission. Can anyone suggest a solution for what I am attempting using blogger and apps script?

Comment: Tanaike: The script at Fig 2 is written on the page where the first error occurs. And after getting that error, I included the script at Fig 3 but got the second error mentioned.